# postgresql ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_apscheduler_djangojob_pkey"

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, apscheduler

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPvSI.png

when i build django(+django-apscheduler),postgresql,nginx i got error above this.

```
    django=4.2.2
    python=3.8.10
    postgresql=14.5
    django-apscheduler=0.6.2
    apscheduler=3.10.1
```

so i try to solve this error, search on google :

1. modify postgres db : **because "django_apscheduler_djangojob_id_seq" doesnt exist**, so i created table("django_apscheduler_djangojobexecution_id_seq" is exist)

```
    CREATE SEQUENCE django_apscheduler_djangojob_id_seq
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    START 1
    CACHE 1
    NO CYCLE;
    CREATE SEQUENCE
```

```
    SELECT setval('django_apscheduler_djangojob_id_seq',(SELECT MAX(id) FROM
    django_apscheduler_djangojob));
```

But it doenst work...

2. comment out "Djangojobstore" : it works but i want to use djangojobstore

```
    in my operator.py :

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


    def delete_dormant_user():
    dormant_user = User.objects.filter(is_active=False)
    dormant_user.delete()


    @util.close_old_connections
    def delete_old_job_executions(max_age=604_800):
    DjangoJobExecution.objects.delete_old_job_executions(max_age)


    class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Runs delete_dormant_user."

    def start(self, *args, **options):
        scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(
            timezone=settings.TIME_ZONE
        )  
       #scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), "default")

        scheduler.add_job(
            delete_dormant_user,
            trigger=CronTrigger(minute="*/3"),
            id="delete_dormant_user",
            max_instances=1,
            replace_existing=True,
        )
        logger.info("Added job 'delete_dormant_user'.")

        scheduler.add_job(
            update_ingredient_links,
            trigger=CronTrigger(day_of_week="0-6", hour="04", minute="00"),
            id="update_ingredient_links",
            max_instances=1,
            replace_existing=True,
        )

        logger.info("Added job 'update_ingredient_links'.")
        scheduler.add_job(
            delete_old_job_executions,
            trigger=CronTrigger(
                day_of_week="mon", hour="05", minute="00"
            ),
            id="delete_old_job_executions",
            max_instances=1,
            replace_existing=True,
        )
        logger.info("Added weekly job: 'delete_old_job_executions'.")
        try:
            logger.info("Starting scheduler...")
            scheduler.start()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            logger.info("Stopping scheduler...")
            scheduler.shutdown()
            logger.info("Scheduler shut down successfully!")
```

```
    in my apps.py :

    class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "users"

    def ready(self):
        if settings.SCHEDULER_DEFAULT:
            from .operator import Command

            Command.start(self)
```

please give me some wisdoms!!

ps. since Mar 6 2022, django-apscheduler hasn't been updated... it can give rise to this error?